# python requests-html get id value of element

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I've benn playing with an example taken from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61408325

this is working and was very helpfull, but I'm strugling with the requests-html documentation.
In this example is it possible to get the id value of the element?

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd 


url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/'

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_scores():
    r = await asession.get(url)
    await r.html.arender()
    return r

results = asession.run(get_scores)
results = results[0]

times = results.html.find("div.event__time")
home_teams = results.html.find("div.event__participant.event__participant--home") 
scores = results.html.find("div.event__scores.fontBold")
away_teams = results.html.find("div.event__participant.event__participant--away")
event_part = results.html.find("div.event__part")


dict_res = defaultdict(list)

for ind in range(len(times)):
    dict_res['times'].append(times[ind].text)
    dict_res['home_teams'].append(home_teams[ind].text)
    dict_res['scores'].append(scores[ind].text)
    dict_res['away_teams'].append(away_teams[ind].text)
    dict_res['event_part'].append(event_part[ind].text)

df_res = pd.DataFrame(dict_res)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the id in a way I don't know if it will be the most suitable.
What I did was search for the  of the entire game

```
match_div = results.html.find("div.event__match")
```

and then get the id from its atributes

```
for ind in range(len(times)):
    id = match_div[ind].attrs['id']
```

I think that must be a more 'direct' way of doing this, but not getting there